# Replacing elements in an HTML file with JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, replace

I am writing some Javascript to:

1. Read in and Parse a JSON file
2. Read in an HTML file (created as a template file)
3. Replace elements in the HTML file with elements from the JSON file.

It is only replacing the first element obj.verb. Can someone please help me figure out where I am getting the syntax or overall approach wrong? Please see the code below and a sample of what the JSON file looks like under that as well.

```
fs.readFile("./tasks/example.json",'utf8', function(err, jsonObjectForHIT){

// parse json file and assign to variable obj
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonObjectForHIT)

// read in template file 
fs.readFile("./tasks/StageOneQuestionTemplate1.html", function(err, addedXML){
// replace value from template with value from json object and assign to variable finalXML
var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace(/VerbGoesHere/g,obj.verb);
var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace(/RoleOne/g,obj.roles[0]);
var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace(/RoleTwo/g,obj.roles[1]);
var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace("RoleThree",obj.roles[2])
}
```

**Sample JSON file referenced above.**

```
{
"verb":"tenir",
"roles":[
            {"name":"with whom"},
            {"name":"thing held"},
            {"name":"conductor"}
        ],
"srcLanguageSentence":{ "text":"Burmah said it had n't held any discussions with SHV and that `` no deal of any nature is in contemplation .",
                        "verb":{"text":"held","sense":"HOLD, conduct","beginOffset":24,"endOffset":28},
                        "roles":[
                                    {"name":"with whom","text":"with SHV","beginOffset":45,"endOffset":53},
                                    {"name":"thing held","text":"any discussions","beginOffset":29,"endOffset":44},
                                    {"name":"conductor","text":"it","beginOffset":13,"endOffset":15}
                                ]
                       },
"tgtLanguageSentences":[
                            { 
                                "text":"Je tiens �galement � mentionner la r�cente Conf�rence , tenue au Canada , sur les enfants touch�s par la guerre .",
                                "verb":{"text":"tenue","beginOffset":57,"endOffset":62},
                                "roles":[
                                    {"name":"thing held","text":"la r�cente Conf�rence , , sur les enfants touch�s par la guerre","beginOffset":33,"endOffset":112},
                                    {"name":"location information","text":"au Canada","beginOffset":63,"endOffset":72}
                                ]
                            }
                       ]
```

}

Comment: After changing that syntax, it is only replacing the last line "var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace("RoleThree",obj.roles[2])". If I comment that line out, it only replaces the one right before it. How can i get it to replace everything (verbs, roles, etc) and not just the last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj.roles[0]` is a object `{"name":"with whom"}`. you cant replace string with object.
you need to refer to property "name" in the object

```
obj.roles[0].name
```

Another problem is that `var finalXML` get a new value every line.
you need to add a new value to the variable, not replcae it.

```
 var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace(/VerbGoesHere/g,obj.verb)
 .replace(/RoleOne/g,obj.roles[0].name)
 .replace(/RoleTwo/g,obj.roles[1].name)
 .replace("RoleThree",obj.roles[2].name);
```

Comment: I am trying to read the different objects within the JSON file as well. For example, "var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace(/SrcLanguageSentenceText/g,obj.srcLanguageSentence[0].text)" to try and read the text, verb and roles from both the "srcLanguageSentence" and the "tgtLanguageSentences" within the JSON file, and place them into the html template. The error says, "cannot read property 'text' of undefined". Can someone please help me with the syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: You dont need the [0] before' text' in `obj.srcLanguageSentence` because is a object, not an array. only in the roles that is array you need it. so is the right code:`var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace(/SrcLanguageSentenceText/g,obj.srcLanguageSentence.t‌​ext)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be `obj.roles[].name` instead of `obj.roles[]`

```
var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace(/RoleOne/g,obj.roles[0].name);
var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace(/RoleTwo/g,obj.roles[1].name);
var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace("RoleThree",obj.roles[2].name);
```

Comment: After changing that syntax, it is only replacing the last line "var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace("RoleThree",obj.roles[2])". If I comment that line out, it only replaces the one right before it. How can i get it to replace everything (verbs, roles, etc) and not just the last line?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I am trying to read the different objects within the JSON file as well. For example, "var finalXML = String(addedXML).replace(/SrcLanguageSentenceText/g,obj.srcLanguageSentence[0].text)" to try and read the text, verb and roles from both the "srcLanguageSentence" and the "tgtLanguageSentences" within the JSON file, and place them into the html template. The error says, "cannot read property 'text' of undefined". Can someone please help me with the syntax to accomplish this?